# How to add new css property in css file through reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sass

I think, it might be silly question to ask but trust me I have case where I want to insert new css property to existing css file ( which are already imported ) . I tried very hard but didn't find any solution to resolve this solution . Could someone please help me in this issue .

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: Actually, I have simple css file which contain some sort of css property . Let suppose I have 8 css properties and I want to insert new css property  based on condition. Total property will be counted ( 9 ) after inserting new property . Is it possible ?

Comment: I think you can't do this with simple css but with sass could be possible. Why you want to do this ? I dont see any relation to react.js.

Comment: Yes, SASS will be okay . Actually I have case in my app where I want to insert new property when condition has been meet .

Comment: so say there is a component called ```<HomeScreen style={styles.homecomtainer}/>``` now you also want to use pass some additional styles to <HomeScreen/> component? It this the use case?

Comment: You can define styles in react.js directly. Maybe it will be easier to solve your problem.  Look at the inline styles in react.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass extra styles to the component separately. :

```js
// react native example
<HomeScreen style={[styles.homeContainer, {width: 100, color: "red"}]}/>
```

here is how you can conditionally pass the specific classname as your specified in the comments section, and use that class name to set the custom styles:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [red, setRed] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className={red ? "redClass" : "greenClass"}>
      <p>hello</p>
      <button onClick={() => setRed(!red)}>Change Color</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is how the css styles for redClass and greenClass looks:

```
.redClass {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.greenClass {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

body {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

[Codesandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-glitter-u86l3?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: I am using library, How to override it CSS based on condition ?

Comment: is it possible to override css class using inline style ?

Comment: ```<HomeScreen style={[styles.homeContainer, conditionIsTrue?{width: 100, color: "red"}:null]}/>```

Comment: this is how you can pass conditional styling.

Comment: I want to override css classname like style = {{'classname':'new-class'}}

Comment: you can do that.

Comment: wait I will give you one example

Comment: Sure , Thanks @ketan

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-glitter-u86l3?file=/src/App.js:0-304